# Add fade to this jQuery rollover

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I add a fade, or animate a change in opacity to this piece of jQuery?

Thanks

```
<script  type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".alain").hover(
        function() {$(this).attr("src","images/rollovers/alain-rollover.png");},
        function() {$(this).attr("src","thumbnails/alain-thumbnail.jpg");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Um, add `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()`?

Answer (score 2):

fade the image out, change the source, fade the image back in :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".alain").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
        var src = e.type == 'mouseenter' ? 'images/rollovers/alain-rollover.png' : 'thumbnails/alain-thumbnail.jpg';

        $(this).fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $(this).prop('src', src).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/adojow/1/edit)

If older browsers aren't an issue, adding and removing a class with CSS3 transitions seems easier.

Comment: +1 but instead of `$(".alain").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e)`, you can just write `$(".alain").hover(function(e)` and it will work.